Why is amount of substance considered a fundamental quantity?
The unit of amount of substance is mole. 1 mole is defined as the amount of substance that contains Avogadro Number (6.022 x 10^23) no. of entities in a substance. It is a fundamental unit.
However, in the measurement of mole, I guess it is measured with the help of another fundamental physical quantity, which is mass.
No. of moles= (mass of a substance) /(molar mass)
Definition of Fundamental Unit
Fundamental units are those which are independent of any other unit.
Why is the ampere a base unit and not the coulomb?
The most upvoted answer seems to explain that ampere can be measured with accuracy in lab but it's difficult to measure charge. In the same way, if I say, amount of substance can't be measured directly in labs, but can be measured with the help of mass, so amount of substance shouldn't be a fundamental physical quantity. But still it is. Why?
Why is the mole/"amount of substance" a dimensional quantity?
Here, the explanation lies mostly for why it's a dimensional quantity. Although there is hint for my question, I am still confused as my question is not only just about why it's a fundamental quantity but also why it will not  be considered in the same way as it is in case of ampere being a fundamental quantity and not charge (link to the question already provided). Also I think mole and mass is related (already I have mentioned). So,it proves amount of substance is related to another fundamental quantity. Why is it still a fundamental quantity itself?

I'd go for the historical perspective - where chemistry and physics mixed and overlapped to study the nature of matter - from experiments on gases, chemical reactions and the origin of "modern" atomic theories to the periodic table and atomic models
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)#history

In what sense is the number of molecules not a fundamental quantity?

This question is similar to: Why is the mole/"amount of substance" a dimensional quantity?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also other duplicates: Why is the mol a fundamental physical quantity? and What are the reasons for making the mole a base SI unit?.

Also related: Is there a need for the unit mole?, Why is the mole an SI unit?, Why are Amperes and moles both base units?, and (from Chemistry SE) Why is the mole a unit of measurement? and Why do people still use the mole (unit) in chemistry?. You are far from being alone in wondering why the mole exists.

@David Bailey I have edited my question. Am I able to explain how my question is different from others and not a duplicate?

How does it differ from the other duplicates noted, especially Why is the mol a fundamental physical quantity?

@David Bailey same question has been asked but no answer covers up that one. One comment says "relation between two things says nothing about them being fundamental or not. You can always invent a number with unit to multiply on to one fundamental property, which converts it into the other - that doesn't say anything special about the two. "...but it doesn't correspond with definition of fundamental quantity and unit

Your question is actually a misunderstanding of what "fundamental" means. Im a theorist, but even we theorists have to agree that, for defining unit systems for humanity to use, it is not important whatsoever for the units to be theoretically pure, only that it be internally consistent. Instead, what is most important is for it to minimise uncertainties across the board; that is why the Ampere is taken as the fundamental and Coulomb the derived. It is the precision engineering needs that trump theoretical cleanliness here.

As for the specific question, the new definition, i.e. fixing Avogadro's constant, means that for every substance, we are newly fixing and defining their molar masses, so that measurements of amount of substance can proceed by your mass/molar mass ratio. Using a fundamental unit to define the molar masses is perfectly fine and sensible. It is the molar mass that links the two fundamental units together, not the mole. So, you are just being confused.

It is not true that the mole is defined in terms of another fundamental quantity (i.e. the kilogram). The current definition of the mole  does not involve the kilogram or any other SI unit:

"One mole contains exactly $6.022140 76\times10^{23}$ elementary entities."

The statement that "No. of moles=(mass of a substance)/(molar mass)" is true, but arguing that this means the mole depends on the kilogram is like claiming that the second is not a fundamental unit because "time = distance/speed".
Molar mass is defined as (mass of a substance)/(amount of substance). In other words, "molar mass" is not a fundamental quantity but is a secondary quantity that can be calculated from the fundamental quantities of mass and amount. The definitions of secondary quantities such as "molar mass" or "speed" can always be rearranged to give equations with a fundamental quantity on the left-hand side and a mix of fundamental and secondary quantities on the right-hand side.
It is true that the current definition of the mole was only adopted in 2019, in part to make it clear that the amount of "elementary entities" is independent of their mass.  The former definition was that the mole was the number of atoms in 12 grams of carbon-12, which related the definition of the mole to the definition of the kilogram.  This is no different, however, than how the definition of the metre depended on the definition of the second, since a metre was defined as distance travelled by light in vacuum in ⁠1/299792458⁠ of a second.
It is worth noting that there really is no such thing as a "fundamental unit", just fundamental constants.  Quoting from the BIPM:

The SI is the system of units in which

the unperturbed ground state hyperfine transition frequency of the caesium-133 atom Δν$_{Cs}$ is 9 192 631 770 Hz
the speed of light in vacuum $c$ is $299 792 458$ m/s
the Planck constant $h$ is $6.626 070 15 \times 10^{–34}$ J s
the elementary charge $e$ is $1.602 176 634 \times 10^{–19}$ C
the Boltzmann constant $k$ is $1.380 649 \times 10^{–23}$ J/K
the Avogadro constant $NA$ is $6.022 140 76 \times 10^{23}$ mol$^{–1}$
the luminous efficacy of monochromatic radiation of frequency $540 \times 10^{12}$ Hz, $K_{cd}$, is 683 lm/W


In this system, the mole actually seems to have the cleanest "fundamental" definition, since it only involves one fundamental constant (Avogadro's number).  In contrast, the definition of the kilogram involves seconds, metres, Planck's constant, the speed of light, and the atomic spectrum of cesium.
Related Questions
Many people wonder why the mole exists, so there are many similar questions whose answers may be worth looking at:

Why is the mole/"amount of substance" a dimensional quantity?
Why is the mol a fundamental physical quantity?
What are the reasons for making the mole a base SI unit?
Is there a need for the unit mole?
Why is the mole an SI unit?
Why are Amperes and moles both base units?

From Chemistry SE

Why is the mole a unit of measurement?
Why do people still use the mole (unit) in chemistry?

Note that some of the questions and answers are from before the 2019 redefinition of the mole, so some of their discussion may no longer be completely relevant.
